# What is the right use of built-in MATLAB functions for visual odometry?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a visual odometry code in MATLAB. I am using the following example ([estimateEssentialMatrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimateessentialmatrix.html)) to obtain the essential matrix. You can open this example typing:

```
openExample('vision/EstimateEssentialMatrixFromAPairOfImagesExample')
```

to the Command Window. Then, I used

```
[relativeOrientation,relativeLocation] = relativeCameraPose(E,cameraParams,inlierPoints1,inlierPoints2);
[rotationMatrix,translationVector] = cameraPoseToExtrinsics(relativeOrientation,relativeLocation);
```

to recover the rotational matrices and translation vector. Then, I concatenated and plotted the translation vector (which indicates the location of the camera),

```
T_t = T_t + R_t * translationVector';
R_t = R_t * rotationMatrix';
location = vertcat(location,[T_t(1),T_t(3)]);
plot3(location(:,1),zeros(size(location(:,1),1),1), location(:,2))
```

where initially,

```
R_t = eye(3);
T_t = [0;0;0];
location = [0,0];
```

**But, I am not getting the right result.** I presume the issue is with the cameraParams object that contains the parameters of the camera.

I used a function (`ReadCameraModel`) that was provided along with the data-set to obtain the camera intrinsics and undistortion LUT. The i/o of the function are as follows:

```
% ReadCameraModel - load camera intrisics and undistortion LUT from disk
%
% [fx, fy, cx, cy, G_camera_image, LUT] = ReadCameraModel(image_dir, models_dir)
%
% INPUTS:
%   image_dir: directory containing images for which camera model is required
%   models_dir: directory containing camera models
%
% OUTPUTS:
%   fx: horizontal focal length in pixels
%   fy: vertical focal length in pixels
%   cx: horizontal principal point in pixels
%   cy: vertical principal point in pixels
%   G_camera_image: transform that maps from image coordinates to the base
%                   frame of the camera. For monocular cameras, this is 
%                   simply a rotation. For stereo camera, this is a rotation                                      % and a translation to the left-most   
%                   lense.
%   LUT: undistortion lookup table. For an image of size w x h, LUT will be an
%        array of size [w x h, 2], with a (u,v) pair for each pixel. Maps pixels
%        in the undistorted image to pixels in the distorted image
```

I used the following code to get the cameraParams object:

```
[fx, fy, cx, cy, G_camera_image, LUT] = ReadCameraModel('./stereo/centre','./model');
K = [fx 0 cx;0 fy cy;0 0 1];       %Intrinsic Matrix of the camera
cameraParams = cameraParameters('IntrinsicMatrix',K);
```

Is this the right way of getting the cameraParams object? If yes, what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Its hard to say, as it looks good. The only way for us to help further is with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
T_t = T_t + R_t * translationVector';
R_t = R_t * rotationMatrix';
location = vertcat(location,[T_t(1),T_t(3)]);
```

with

```
R_t = rotationMatrix * R_t;
T_t = T_t + (R_t * translationVector');
location = horzcat(location, T_t);
```